# Python LoopingCall Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

So Ive made a small server, there is a looping call. The looping call runs fine when there is more than one protocol involved. Let me explain. It is a game server, usually I would start the match with 2 or more players. This would cause the looping call to actually work. However Ive made it only 1 player for now, with bots in game. Now the looping call does not run.
Here is the code:

```
class SurvivMatch:

def __init__(self, players, loot):
    self.players = players
    self.loot = loot
    self.state = MATCH_STATE_ACTIVE
    self.pendingShutdown = False
    self.shutdownTime = 0
    self.timer = LoopingCall(self.update)   <- this is not running 
    self.timer.start(0.07) 
    self.id = 0
    self.playerloot = []
    self.boxloot = []
```

Comment: please show us the LoopingCall function in detail.

Comment: Also see http://sscce.org/

Comment: Add details of update method. how much time it will take to finish, may your system getting hang if that function taking more time, as you started looping with 0.07 seconds.